# Ionic Run time Error: Uncaught (in promise): cordova_not_available

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working on an ionic project which recently worked perfectly after some updation its magically stop working. 
`ionic serve` command run successfully on browser but when i run project on mobile its always shows error `uncaught (in promise): cordova_not_available`

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Node : v8.9.4
    npm  : 5.6.0 
    OS   : macOS High Sierra
```

Please suggest any solution. Thanks.
Here the plugins list:

```
> cordova plugin ls
cordova-android-support-gradle-release 1.2.0 "cordova-android-support-gradle-release"
cordova-plugin-android-permissions 1.0.0 "Permissions"
cordova-plugin-badge 0.8.7 "Badge"
cordova-plugin-camera 4.0.2 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-console 1.1.0 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.1 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-opener2 2.0.19 "File Opener2"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-filechooser 1.0.1 "File Chooser"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 2.0.2 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.0.5 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.16 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-local-notification 0.9.0-beta.2 "LocalNotification"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.1 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.3.2 "SocialSharing"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 4.0.3 "Diagnostic"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
phonegap-plugin-push 2.1.3 "PushPlugin"
```

This is the file code where this error is occured

```
if (this.platform.is('android') || this.platform.is('ios')) {
      this.CS.notifications();
      this.push.hasPermission()
        .then((res: any) => {
          if (res.isEnabled) {
            this.CS.pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) => {
              this.CS.device_id = registration.registrationId;
              this.loginService.login(this.user).subscribe( (res)  => {
                if(this.loginService.isLoggedIn == true) {

                }else{
                  this.show = true;
                }
              });
            });
          } else {
            this.CS.alertMessage("error", "We do not have permission to send push notifications.")
          }
        });
    }else{
      this.loginService.login(this.user).subscribe( (res)  => {
        if(this.loginService.isLoggedIn == true) {
          this.NavCtrl.setRoot(GroupsComponent);
          /*this.CS.activeGroupId = 35;
          this.CS.group_chat = true;
          this.NavCtrl.push(TabsWrapperPage);*/
        }else{
          this.show = true;
        }
      });
    }
```

[image]

Comment: can you share login function ....

Comment: I have already paste the code of login function and i got error on `this.push.hasPermission()` this line

Comment: this function is work on real android device....

Comment: No. its not working on real device

Comment: can you share loginService login method?

Comment: Actually app is not asking for push notification permission. Please explain how to set permission for push notification?

Answer (score 0):

Cordova is only available on a real device and without live reloading on.
You can check if you have access to it by:

```
if (window.hasOwnProperty("cordova")) {
 //plugins init that need cordova
}
```